# Positioning sprite image

Tags: css, image, sprite

So, I am trying to make a sprite image for my home page, but I can't seem to position it right. Here is the image so you can see how I want it to look like:

[image]

And here is how it looks like when I put it on my webpage:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
#leagues {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

#clubs {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat -620px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#nations {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat 0 -220px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

#international-competitions {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat -940px 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 420px;
}

#domestic-competitions {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat -520px -220px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#national-teams-competitions {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat 0 -440px;
  width: 660px;
  height: 200px;
}

#discontinued {
  background: url('img/mainmenu.png') no-repeat -680px -440px;
  width: 660px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code you provided doesn't provide enough context to illustrate the problem. Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answer, but that is all I got. The code I wrote is working, only the images are not positioned the way I would like.

Comment: That code doesn't render anything. Where's your html? And assuming the images aren't positioned, you would need to post the sprite, too.